# JQGrid stops responding / times out after a few minutes

Tags: jquery, web, timeout, controls

Not sure if it's just recently, but JQGrid stops responding and functioning after a few minutes, maybe 3-5 minutes now.  Sorting columns doesn't do anything, changing pages of data.  They hyperlinks work to bring up other things just like a normal web page, but the user has to refresh the page to get these controls to work.  Is there a timeout variable or how does this normally work?

Comment: Are you working with a large number of rows, say hundreds or thousands on a single page?

Comment: The result set may have about 100, but I don't think a thousand would be close.  I did see this in firebug.

Comment: GET http://sww.sas.com/csd/VisitorMgmt/jsps/ajaxData...8308411&rows=15&page=2&sidx=contactName&sord=asc     500 Internal Server Error  60ms  
  
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://sww.sas.com/csd/VisitorMgmt/jsps/ajaxData/griddata.jsp?_search=false&nd=1364398308411&rows=15&page=2&sidx=contactName&sord=asc"; 500 Internal Server Error  60ms jquery-1.7.2.js (line 8240)

Comment: This is happening approx 45 seconds - 1 minute after no usage

Comment: With an HTTP 500, are you sure the root of your problem is not on the server, instead of jqGrid?

Comment: Totally not sure about that.  It might be general weirdness, I'm gonna see if I can have everything bounced tonight to get a fresh start in the morning and see if there is a difference.  Thanks.